# Why was StringRepeat designed so that StringRepeat[s, 0] throws an error?

Tags: string-manipulation, language-design

**Update**

In version 13.2 `StringRepeat[" ", 0]` produces an empty string.

---

I'm wondering about the rationale behind the design decision that leads to the following expression throwing an error:

```
StringRepeat[" ", 0]

(* StringRepeat::intp: Positive integer expected at position 2 in StringRepeat[ ,0]. >> *)
```

I would expect it to just return an empty string.

I'd like to understand what reasons could be behind this decision.

Comment: I think "bug" is probably too strong a word, but it seems like an infelicitous choice, given how similar functions (`Table`, `ConstantArray` et c.) work.

Comment: IMO quite possibly an oversight, why don't you contact support and ask?  This is one of the recently added convenience functions (some of which are not yet up to the usual quality standards).

Comment: I'll go ahead and report this as a suggestion for you.

Comment: I can't think of too many examples in my head, but I'm sure if I think I can come up with some plausible logic for why this should be :).

Comment: This would affect other functions like StringPadRight, StringPadLeft and would be impossible with StringPartition

Comment: I sent an email to Wolfram asking about this behavior.

Comment: You could always say for example that allowing 0 length strings breaks some equalities like:

StringPartition[StringRepeat[str, n], StringLength@str] == 
 Table[str, {n}]

Which is true for any whole number n that isn't zero. But then again, I guess this just points out that Table[1, {0}] returns {} which just shows that your suggestion would make the behavior more consistent.

Comment: @lericr - that should be an answer to this question rather than an edit.

Comment: @JasonB. oh, okay, thanks!

Comment: @JasonB. I added an answer, but I kind of think having the update in the question would also be helpful so folks can see immediately that the issue has been resolved. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

In version 13.2 `StringRepeat[" ", 0]` produces an empty string.